# Converting C# code to php have different result

Tags: c#, php

I have code using C# and want to try to translate to php code but always got different result in php version

C#

```
private static string encryptDecrypt(string input)
 {
     char[] key = { 'X' }; //Any chars will work, in an array of any size
     char[] output = new char[input.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
     {
         output[i] = (char)(input[i] ^ key[i % key.Length]);
     }

     return new string(output);
 }

string vb64 = "DAAdAAAADAAVAAsAHwA=";
string decrypted = encryptDecrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(vb64)));
Console.WriteLine("Decrypted:" + decrypted);
```

output  Decrypted:TEXTMSG

PHP

```
function encryptDecrypt($input) {
    $key = ['X']; 
    $output = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        $output .= $input[$i] ^ $key[$i % count($key)];
    }
    return $output;
}
$vb64 = "DAAdAAAADAAVAAsAHwA=";
$decrypted = encryptDecrypt(base64_decode($vb64));
echo "decrypted ".$decrypted.PHP_EOL;
```

decrypted TXEXXXTXMXSXGX

EDIT:  need to add mb_convert_encoding to set to  UTF-16 encryptDecrypt(mb_convert_encoding(base64_decode($vb64), "", "UTF-16LE"))

Comment: Just so you know, `Encoding.Unicode` != `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: Are you sure `count($key)` is correct? I think you wanted to use `strlen($key)` [Line 5].

Comment: The two codes are different. What you are doing in the loop for PHP is not the same as the original C# code.

Comment: i  copied the code from https://github.com/KyleBanks/XOREncryption

Comment: @user I recommend posting your own answer to your question, since I misunderstood which language was "the problem" so to speak, and I'm unable to provide a PHP answer. :)